# Amplify Subscription - Using a Filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have created a subscription that triggers when I create an invitation. When I don't pass any filter, the subscription works correctly. However, when I use the user_id filter, the subscription doesn't return anything at the time of creation.

Someone can help me?

**Amplify Model:**

```
type Subscription {
  onCreateInvitation(user_id: ID): Invitation
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createInvitation"])
    @auth(rules: [
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
    ])
}
```

**Graphql Subscription request:**

```
subscription MySubscription {
  onCreateInvitation(user_id: "12345") {
    id
  }
}
```